# jQuery: Identify a value of declared variable is the same as the value within a list of keys in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am have a set of array in `json` as followed:

```
{"status":200,"success":true,"result":
[{"id":"0","name":"user1","type":"mf","message":"bonjour user1"},
{"id":"1","name":"user2","type":"ff","message":"hello user2"},
{"id":"2","name":"user3","type":"mm","message":"konnichiwa user3"},
{"id":"3","name":"user4","type":"mf","message":"ni hao user4"},
{"id":"4","name":"user5","type":"ff","message":"high 5! user5"}]}
```

I would like to ask how could I identify if the value of a declared variable (eg. "getName" with the value of "user1") is the same as a value within the list of "name" keys in the array?

Below is my attempt and you might find my full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/2/):

```
var apiUrl = "https://sheetsu.com/apis/f924526c"; 

$.getJSON(apiUrl,function(json){

    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

        var getName = $.each(getName, function(content, json){
            console.log(json.name);
            console.log(getName[content].id);
        });

        var identifiedId = $.each(getName, function(){
            console.log(this.name);
            console.log(this.id);
        })
});
```

Comment: Based on the json example in your question, what is your desired result?

Comment: My scenario is like this: There is a form for user to type in their name (eg. user1). The result (value) would then be mapped to my json API, to see if there is a same value from the "name" key. If so, //do something.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in more detail. Your declaration of `getName` is undefined

Comment: should be sending that name to api and check there. Doesn't make sense to dump the whole database to look it up in javascript

Comment: @charlietfl Hi, I created the API from my Google spreadsheet with sheetsu.com, that's why there is no API documentation available :P Or is there a suggestion from you please? x

Comment: I had never heard of sheetsu.com. I checked it out, but it does not look like you can request a single record.

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder It works with the help from Bas below and I have updated my code on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/4/ just in case if u want to check it out:))) The only thing is that the image is not loading... apart from that, everything works! YAYYY! x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your code, but in order to loop trough the `json` and find the key value you want use:

```
$.each(json.result, function() {
     //here you can store id.
     $.each(this, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ' ' + value);
        //test if key  = username you want and store value
     });
});
```

You can also do it with one loop since you know which key to check

```
$.each(json.result, function() {
    if (this.name == "name you look for"){
        idyouneed = this.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bas, Thank you very much for your reply. I tried to print the values in the "name" key only, but it doesnt work with this (console.log(key.name);) under the console log u suggested above, may I ask what would you suggest please? x

Comment: If you want to specify the name key you can do that in the first foreach loop. The second loop, loops over all keys in each result. So you can also add `if key == name` in the second `$.each` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bas:))) x

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to see if a particular name is in your json file.

This would be one way to do this. The result part of your json, is an array of objects. You can loop through this array.

```
var nameToCheck = "user1";

$.each(json.result, function(res) {
     if (res["name"] == nameToCheck) {
         // do something
     }

});
```

However, as someone commented, it may be more efficient to use your api for the existence of a particular name or user. Check the api documentation.